# How to filter element except showing all data

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the All option in filtering element. How can I do that?

I removed the line for 'all' , but it is still showing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="portfolio-flters">
            <li data-filter=".filter-app">Dhaka</li>
            <li data-filter=".filter-card">Rajshahi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which one is the line for 'all'? What did you do to remove All option? We do not know what you have done to help you. Please share your JS code

Comment: can we have all the code?

Answer (score -1):

### Use This One

- First add jQuery link and than copy jQuery code and paste it..

```js
$('#portfolio-flters li').removeAttr("data-filter");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="portfolio-flters">
            <li data-filter=".filter-app">Dhaka</li>
            <li data-filter=".filter-card">Rajshahi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```